# What does #equal_set do in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, serialization

I tried looking online but couldn't find anything on `equal_set` for Rspec. I know it's used to test a serializer but that's it.

Comment: I don't think it's part of RSpec officially. It's probably a custom matcher that your code base is using, or an RSpec helper from another installed gem. I'd guess that it's like `match_array` but treats the arrays being compared as a set of unique elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used in the gem [peck-on-rails](https://github.com/Fingertips/Peck-On-Rails) which is an extension for [Peck](https://github.com/Fingertips/Peck) to make testing Rails easier. Peck is a concurrent spec framework.

Below is the `equal_set` method, refer [here](https://github.com/Fingertips/Peck-On-Rails/blob/de74f14d5e41c6d7ae2e9bb6e3692e78a564474d/lib/peck_on_rails/assertions.rb).

```
def equal_set(*others)
  left, right = @this, others
  left.flatten! if left.respond_to?(:flatten)
  right.flatten! if right.respond_to?(:flatten)

  message = "Expected sets to be #{!@negated ? 'equal' : 'unequal'}: #{left.inspect} - #{right.inspect}"
  satisfy(message) { Set.new(left) == Set.new(right) }
end
```